# Can I switch between wkhtmltopdf libraries programmatically?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have several versions of `wkhtmltopdf` libraries installed on my server. I want to be able to switch between them programmatically when I'm about to render them because we have several development teams and they use different versions of `wkhtmltopdf`. Different `wkhtmltopdf` version are giving totally different rendered results, which is weird. Is it possible to switch between them programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full code but i try to this type of code may it's work for you:

```python
import os
from openerp import tools  # this odoo config file master/openerp/tools/which.py
import subprocess
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def find_in_path(name):
    path = os.environ.get('PATH', os.defpath).split(os.pathsep)
    if tools.config.get('bin_path') and tools.config['bin_path'] != 'None':
        path.append(tools.config['bin_path'])
    return tools.which(name, path=os.pathsep.join(path))


def _get_wkhtmltopdf_bin():
    return find_in_path('wkhtmltopdf')

wkhtmltopdf_state = 'install'
try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        [_get_wkhtmltopdf_bin(), '--version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    print "prrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr", process.communicate()[0]
    # here write your logic
    #
    #
    #
    #
except (OSError, IOError):
    _logger.info('You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports.')
```